What is / how do I find the general ratios of all of the materials used in a cmos chip?
I am doing a life cycle assessment of a CMOS chip. But I am struggling a lot in finding the general ratios or quantities of the materials used in a chip, which is necessary for calculation of environmental impacts. I can't even find broad ranges. I am new to electrical engineering  (I have an env sci background) and so I don't know a lot about the different parts of a chip.
Does anyone here either know or have suggestions for resources for how I can determine the quantities (general/ranges or specific) of materials in a chip? (ex] 50% silicon, 20% aluminum, etc). I am aware about fill ratio and things like that. Just looking for general percentages. It's hard even to find the uses of each material in a chip (for example, what is gallium/germanium used for? I can't find anything).

Since packaging of the chip is the only thing likely to have an environmental impact (Si does not appreciably degrade, and is no more harmful than SiO2, sand, for example), and packaging is proprietary, you might consult the manufacturers, who likely have a materials list for RoHS, as required by law in some locales.

One thing to figure in is yield < 1. I take price to be a 0th order indicator of environmental impact up to 1st use.
